# Insert the new row by taking the last deleted CommentNo in the order they deleted

Tags: sql, database, sql-insert

```
CommentID   CommentNo   Comments    IsDeleted   DocId
1               1        test1        1          123
2               2        test2        1          123
3               3        test3        0          123
4               4        test4        0          123
```

From the above  commentID is an autoincretement, Initially CommentNo 1, was deleted and then CommentNo 2 is deleted. While inserting the new records the CommentNo should start with missing CommentNo 1 followed by 2

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: Curious why trying to (re)use old values matters? ... That sounds like some past managers that I've dealt with that worry about 'gaps' in numbers, and none of them knew SQL. We simply renumbered things on the output, and they were none the wiser.

Comment: Please specify the `RDBMS`  and version you are using to increase the chance of getting an answer. Fundamentally the auto increment columns should never be reset or manually set with a value just because previous rows were marked as deleted. If you are only trying to update the `CommentNo` column, assuming it isn't AI & Unique, it could potentially be done but not recommended.